# Access status bar not showing during query execution

Tags: ms-access, office365

While running reports, we have various points where the MS Access status bar message is updated to indicate the progress (what step number/description of the report process that the database is on).  We've done this for years, maybe a decade.

Recently someone noticed that while the status messages were showing when the report process started, the status messages disappear after a minute or two (the entire report takes 10 or 20 mins to run).  I did some debugging, and it seems that after every query starts, the status message stays displayed for only about 5 or 10 seconds, then it goes blank until that query is completed.

If I'm stepping through the code with F8, then as soon as the query finishes, the status is visible again.  But if I let the code fly, then the status never returns (probably because it moves to the next query too fast, where the status is hidden again).

We just recently upgraded from Office 2016 to Office 365.  So some suspicion that was related.

I couldn't find anything on this googling, but curious if anyone has noticed anything similar in Office 365.  Or has any idea of what is causing this new problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UI to update, you need to call `DoEvents` after updating the status bar message.

Add a `DoEvents` for each time you update the status bar.

Note that this might change the code functionally if the code changes things (e.g. updates fields) that causes events to fire.